# What is the proper way to define different object structures inside an array swagger schema?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I hope this is a legit question, I searched everywhere for an example or any source of information on how to do this. I tried this https://github.com/fotinakis/swagger-blocks/issues/17 as well. But the same result.

The end result I would like to get generated is below: 

`{
  "name": "Awesome Promotion",
  "description": "30% off",
  "qualifiers": [
      {
         "id": 12,
         "type": "Rental"
      },
      {
          "id": 13,
          "type": "Qualifier",
          "user_id": 23
      },
      {
          "id": 14,
          "type": "First",
          "location_id": 32 
      }
  ]`

I have the model writen out like this:

`swagger_schema :PromotionResponse do
      property :name, type: :string, example: 'Awesome Promotion'
      property :description, type: :string, example: '30% off'
      property :qualifiers do
        key :type, :array
        items do
          property :id, type: :integer, example: 2
          property :type, type:  :string, exmple: 'Location'
        end
      end
    end`

What gets generated by swagger right now:

`{
  "name": "Awesome Promotion",
  "description": "30% off",
  "qualifiers": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "Location"
    }
  ]
}`

What is the proper way to define different object structures inside an array schema?